# How to download base64 pdf files from website on iOS

Tags: javascript, pdf, download

I'm struggling with this issue that I can download documents on chrome but not on iOS devices

Whenever I try, I get "Not allowed to navigate top frame to data URL" error.

Is there a way to do this with JS?

Extra question:

Is getting base64 encoded pdf to client and then downloading is a good solution or do you have any other suggestions? Please bear in mind that there are a lot of documents so adding every doc to assets is not possible.

I tried the code below and it worked on desktop devices but not on iOS.

```
        const a = document.createElement("a");
        a.href = "data:application/pdf;base64,BASE_64_PDF";
        a.download = "file.pdf";
        a.click();
```

Comment: I can't test on iOS but maybe if you turn the base64 data URI into a `Blob` object using `fetch` and then download that Blob it may work.

Comment: Thanks for the tip! Found a code that will help me turn it into a blob and then integrated that to my own code. It seems like it works

Answer (score 0):

So after [Danny](https://stackoverflow.com/users/18241830/danny) mentioned Blob, i found a code that helps me to transform my b64 pdf to a Blob ([Blob transformation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16245768/22854616)). And it seems like it works on iOS aswell.

```
   const b64toBlob = (b64Data, contentType = "", sliceSize = 512) => {

    const byteCharacters = atob(b64Data);
    const byteArrays = [];

    for (
      let offset = 0;
      offset < byteCharacters.length;
      offset += sliceSize
    ) {
      const slice = byteCharacters.slice(offset, offset + sliceSize);
      const byteNumbers = new Array(slice.length);

      for (let i = 0; i < slice.length; i++) {
        byteNumbers[i] = slice.charCodeAt(i);
      }

      const byteArray = new Uint8Array(byteNumbers);
      byteArrays.push(byteArray);
    }

    const blob = new Blob(byteArrays, { type: contentType });

    return blob;
  };

  const contentType = "data:application/pdf";
  const b64Data = "BASE_64_DOC";

  const blob = b64toBlob(b64Data, contentType);
  const blobUrl = URL.createObjectURL(blob);

  const a = document.createElement("a");

  a.href = blobUrl;
  a.download = "file_name.pdf";
  a.click();
```

Comment: It's so good you managed to solve it. But with `fetch` it would be much easier. Unless somehow the Content Security Policy of the website does not allow it.

Comment: Hi @Danny can you give a sample code for how to fetch it if you don't mind?

Comment: you just have to do a get request with the data URI using `fetch` and get a `Blob` from it, like `fetch(dataURI).then(response => response.blob()).then(blob => /* do something with the blob*/)`

Comment: fetch works great, thanks for the tip, it was exactly what I was looking for. Only downside is it's asynchronous